# Login Prompt when refreshing access data connection from Excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, connection, prompt

I have a user that gets  a prompt when opening one of my file (no one else get it).

The file has a connection to an access table using a SQL command.

The connection string gets updated automatically when opening the file to match the local adress of the accdb file.

The connection string is the following:

```
DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=C:\Users\t73648\Google Drive\computer\documents\opex\dmc mbo\final files\DMCMBOTable.accdb;DefaultDir=C:\Users\t73648\Google Drive\computer\documents\opex\dmc mbo\final files;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;
```

The command in the following:

```
SELECT * FROM GAreaGPL GAreaGPL
WHERE (GAreaGPL.GPL='test')
```

It does not generate problems with other users.

The pop up looks like that:

[image: pop Up]

Obviously there is no password I can provide as the DB is fully unlock.

Thanks for helping me out on this one

Comment: Look at the odbc datasource for that user.

Comment: Very sorry for the late answer. I changed the approach, create a refresh using DAO. Thks for the answer